# Read xlsx file as dataframe inside .rar pack in python directly

Tags: python, pandas, winrar

I need help to read xlsx file present inside rar pack. I am using below code, however get an error. Is there any better way to read/extract file?

```
rar = glob.glob(INPATH + "*xyz*.rar*")
rf = rarfile.RarFile(rar[0])
for f in rf.infolist():
    print(f.filename, f.file_size)
    df = pd.read_excel(rf.read(f))
```

> rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool

Answer (score 0):

According to the brief [PyPI docs](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/), you need `unrar` installed and on your PATH in order for the module to work. It does not implement the RAR unpacking algorithm itself.

(Presumably you need `rar` as well, for creating archives.)